# 1st datatable breaking 2nd datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have well functioning datatable(1st) on one page of my webapp and decided to make another datatable(2nd) on a different page.  A portion of the js/jquery associated with the 1st datatable, when commented out, allows the 2nd table to function properly. When not commented out the table returns "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries" as if someone were to have searched for something not at all contained in the table. I've resorted to even using the exact example html/jquery that they use in the initial example on datatables.net and still have issues.

Below is the code pertaining to the 1st table that when commented out allows the 2nd datatable to function fully.

```
    $(document).ready( function () {

  /* Custom filtering function which will search data in column four between two values */
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        var min = $('#min').val();
        var max = $('#max').val();
        var date =  data[4]; // use data for the age column

        if ( ( min == '' && max == '' ) ||
             ( min == '' && date <= max ) ||
             ( min <= date && '' == max ) ||
             ( min <= date && date <= max ) )
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);

  var table = $('#datat').DataTable();

   // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
        $('#min, #max').keyup( function() {
            table.draw();
        } );
} );
```

I'm not sure what in the above code might be breaking my 2nd datatable.

Comment: Is there any error message in the dev tool?

Comment: are min, max in both the pages?

Comment: @WimPruiksma, no error.
Vanojx1, no the 2nd page/table has no min/max sort field

Answer (score 1):

if #min and #max doesn't exists your filter wont work, add this to handle this case:

```
if( $('#min').length == 0 || $('#max').length == 0)
    return true
```